# xHTML 1.0 strict - Validate iFrames

Tags: validation, xhtml, iframe

Is it possible to validate iFrames in xhtml 1.0 strict? Preferably without any use of javascript to inject the iframe into the page.

I know there is no point in validating just for the sake of validation, but lets just say that I like the green validation message on w3c ;) (I am forced by factors beyond my control to use iframes)

Or maybe there is something very similar I can use in xHTML to get iframe-like behavior without losing compatibility across different browsers? (object?)

Perhaps there is a way to add a second doctype containing iframe rules?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i'm not sure but I think you can include another page with object as you suggest.

```
<object data="/another.html" type="text/html"></object>
```

Comment: To clarify on this: It won't work in IE, that's why I'm now using <!--[if IE]> to show it as an iframe in IE. The object will be used in other browsers. Technically the iframe will be a comment though, so it validates!

Comment: Wonderful - duplication of effort and hacks to hide content from the validator. It would be much easier to just use Transitional (or fix the design to not use iframes).

Comment: no, i agree with the OP. If it's a comment then it is not a part of the DOM, and compliant browsers can use it in a compliant way. A few extra lines of code is a small price for supporting IE, the most non-compliant browser in existence.

Comment: You can be compliant without having to support two different methods for achieving the same thing by using Transitional.

Answer (score 0):

If you need iframes, use Transitional instead of Strict. The point of it is for when you need to use legacy features like iframes.

Comment: Isn't the whole _power_ of HTML 4.x Transitional supposed to be available in HTML/XHTML Strict, even if you have to use CSS to get at it?

Comment: @Stewart — no. You can simulate the **layout** features of frames with CSS, but not their other properties. You can achieve some limited loading of external content with JS, but that just adds another batch of problems.