# Valuable flair of MathOverflow, in XHTML mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, mime-types, stackexchange, html

I would like to include the [“piece of valuable flair™”](https://mathoverflow.net/users/flair) of MathOverflow on my webpage.

Problem : I want my webpage to be XHTML5, i.e. served with the MIME type `application/xhtml+xml` and the script of MathOverflow uses `document.write` which doesn’t exists in XHTML. I tried to get the data by JSON and put the data on the page, but some of the JSON data are string representing HTML code, and of course I cannot use `innerHTML` or the `.html()` method of jQuery.

How can I parse the HTML in the JSON, in order to be able to use it with an XML MIME type?
Or is there a clean way to include the flair, standards complying, and without having to change the MIME type to `text/html`?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [iframe method](https://mathoverflow.net/users/flair), but replace the `iframe` element with an `object` element to be [XHTML strict compliant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985333/xhtml-1-0-strict-validate-iframes) for backwards compatibility and mobile usability:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
  <head>
  <title>Flair</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <object data="https://mathoverflow.net/users/flair/1459.html?theme=clean" style="overflow:hidden"></object>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you use XHTML5, you actually can use `iframe` and still be valid.